# Produce repeating blocks inside a terraform resource

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am fairly new to terraform and trying to create a `google_compute_backend_service` using terraform and there are multiple backend blocks inside the resource as shown below:

```
resource "google_compute_backend_service" "app-backend" {
  log_config {
    enable      = "true"
    sample_rate = "1"
  }

  name             = "app-backend"
  port_name        = "http-34070"
  project          = "my-project"
  protocol         = "HTTP"
  session_affinity = "NONE"
  timeout_sec      = "30"

  backend {
    group = "insatnce-group1"
  }

  backend {
    group = "instance-group2"
  }

  backend {
    group = "instance-group3"
  }

  health_checks = [google_compute_http_health_check.app-http-l7.name]
}
```

As seen in the code block above the `backend` block repeats multiple times. I want to make it dynamic so I do not have to write multiple blocks manually.

I tried the following:

Created a variable in the `variables.tf` file that contains all the instance groups:

```
variable "groups" {
  type = list(object({
    name = string
  }))
  default = [{ name = "instance-group1"}, 
             { name = "instance-group2"}, 
             { name = "instance-group3"}]
}
```

And modified my resource block to this:

```
resource "google_compute_backend_service" "app-backend" {
  log_config {
    enable      = "true"
    sample_rate = "1"
  }

  name             = "app-backend"
  port_name        = "http-34070"
  project          = "my-project"
  protocol         = "HTTP"
  session_affinity = "NONE"
  timeout_sec      = "30"

  dynamic "backend" {
    for_each = var.groups
    iterator = item
    group = item.value.name
  }

  health_checks = [google_compute_http_health_check.app-http-l7.name]
}
```

However, when I execute `terraform plan` I get the following error:

```
Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on backend_service.tf line 15, in resource "google_compute_backend_service" "app-backend":
│   15:     group = item.value.name
│
│ An argument named "group" is not expected here.
```

Where am I going wrong? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the [dynamic blocks documentation](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks) for the syntax. Otherwise, you had the right idea.

```
dynamic "backend" {
  for_each = var.groups

  content {
    group = backend.value.name
  }
}
```

You can also simplify the variable structure to make this even easier.

```
variable "groups" {
  type    = set(string)
  default = ["instance-group1", "instance-group2", "instance-group3"]
}

dynamic "backend" {
  for_each = var.groups

  content {
    group = backend.value
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you, this approach worked. With ```set(string)``` this becomes less complicated.